# Picking up files in SFTP Server then create it as a TABLE in Database using DELL BOOMI

Tags: sql, boomi

Can anyone direct me or teach me on how to do a process in Dell Boomi that will get all the *.csv files in a SFTP Server then create them in SQL Server (Database Table)

The Sample CSV File in SFTP:

[image]

In which, the first row will be the Table Name,
second row is the Column Names, 
Rest will be the Values

**Note: The process should work with more than 10 CSV Files**

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed format for tables then you can write SQL scripts inside Program Command Shape and make them run based upon input from .csv file and by making use of the Condition Shape.

Otherwise, in case if you don't have fixed table schema then you need to think of way of writing dynamic SQL for creating tables on the GO.